# How can I get all records with condition 'username=email' from Django Users.objects.all()

Tags: django-views

how can I get all data with condition username=email in User.objects.all()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLFCu.png)

```
    class ItemListView(ServerSideDatatableView):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        columns = ['id', 'username', 'email']
```

Comment: Please share *code*, not images of code.

Comment: The image isn't actually a code but a question

Comment: just copy paste the text in the image as code fragment. By making it an image, it is less convenient to read it, people with visual impairments can not work with screen readers, if later the image is removed the question is no longer relevant, etc.

Comment: see http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I managed to add a code and still attached the image as for precise question

Answer (score 2):

You can filter with an [**`F`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) to refer to a field:

```
from django.db.models import F

User.objects.filter(email=F('username'))
```

or you can exclude these with:

```
from django.db.models import F

User.objects.exclude(email=F('username'))
```

Comment: bruh it actually work, but how about the vice versa? sorry, I'm just a newbie in django. email<>F('username') and email!=F('username') doesn't seems to work

Comment: I wanted to upvote your answer but I'm also new in stackoverflow and can't upvote anyone, my bad.

Comment: hi @Willern, thank you so much for the help. It seems hard searching for the answer with just using the question for searching. All works now, thanks so much!! God bless you man!!